# type does not satisfy interface (method has pointer receiver)

Tags: go, generics

is it possible to do something like this:

```golang
package main

type reader interface {
   read()
}

type hello int

func (*hello) read() {}

func set[T reader](a *T) {
   var b T
   *a = b
}

func main() {
   i := hello(1)
   set(&i)
}
```

no matter what I change I get an error.

Answer (score 3):

Type `hello` doesn't implement method `read`. The interface `reader` is implemented by the type `*hello`. That is why the call `set(&i)` has the signature `set(T)`, not `set(*T)`, and go can't derive the type for the generic.

What you need is call `set(*T)` such that `*T is reader`:

```
package main

type reader interface {
    read()
}

type hello int

func (*hello) read() {}

func set[T any, U interface {*T;reader}](a U) {
    var b T
    *a = b
}

func main() {
    i := hello(1)
    set(&i)
}
```